# Dynamically initialize a struct given an array of strings

Tags: arrays, go, struct, go-gorm

I am using `gorm` to query and manage mysql. The function named `SyncDB` in the following snippet migrates the latest user schema found in the `user.go` file under `schema` directory.

```
    package db

    import (
       "my-server/db/schema"
       "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    )

    func SyncDB(db *gorm.DB) {

        db.AutoMigrate(&schema.User{})

    }
```

I have multiple files under the `schema` directory. I tried reading all the file names under the directory `schema` and have the filenames as an array which looks like:

```
filenames := []string{
   "user.go",
   "password.go",
   "profile.go",
}
```

Is there a way to use `filenames` array and dynamically call:

```
db.AutoMigrate(&schema.User{})
```

For example, `&schema.User{}` gets replaced by `&schema.Password{}` in the next call. How could I make this thing dynamic?

Comment: Definitely there is no way with `GORM` (I could find any documentation) but the question if we could do this with `GO`?

Comment: You can't get types (or values of those types) by their `string` names.

Comment: @icza `AutoMigrate` accepts the interface type. Could we utilize the behavior?

Comment: No, you need to pass values of your type (or pointers), and that you cannot get just by their string names in Go.

Comment: @icza Does casting work with `Go`?

Comment: There is [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) and type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).

Answer (score 0):

There is not way to send the file.
I would suggest to create `slice of struct` and pass that into `AutoMigrate` as mentioned below:

```
values := []interface{}{&schema.User{}, &profile.Profile{}, &password.Password{}}

if err := DB.AutoMigrate(values...).Error; err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("No error should happen when create table, but got %+v", err))
}
```

Comment: This is no different from directly passing to `AutoMigrate`. This does not have a solution with `gorm` but the question is if there is a way with `go`.